# Html Form with Javascript Submit sometimes doesn't record information

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So, I have a small form written to more easily record information from my clients. I don't have it hooked up to a dB right now, it just reprints the client information on the screen. For some reason, if it sits in the browser for too long, upon hitting the submit button the information will just disappear and won't reprint to the screen. The typed information still shows up in the URL bar upon submit, but I'm not sure why this is happening. If anybody has a fix that would be awesome. I have attached my code below.

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang = "en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>ProFormer</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "testing.css" />

    <script>

        function display(form){

            form.o_name.value = form.name.value;

            form.o_city.value = form.city.value;

            form.o_state.value = form.state.value;

            form.o_phone.value = form.phone.value;

            form.o_email.value = form.email.value;

            form.o_dob.value = form.dob.value;

            form.o_gender.value = form.gender.value;

            form.o_heightandweight.value = form.heightandweight.value;

            form.o_tobacco.value = form.tobacco.value;

            form.o_hc.value = form.hc.value;

            form.o_baddiseases.value = form.baddiseases.value;

            form.o_rx.value = form.rx.value;

            form.o_pain.value = form.pain.value;

            form.o_insuredstatus.value = form.insuredstatus.value;

            form.o_premiumrange.value = form.premiumrange.value;

            form.o_notes.value = form.notes.value;

            return false;

        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form name="input" action="" method="get" onsubmit="return display(this);">

        <section>

            <div class = "scrollWrapper">

            <table>

                <tr>

                    <th>NAME: </th>

                    <td><output name="o_name" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <th>CITY: </th>

                    <td><output name="o_city" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>

                </tr>

                

                <tr>

                    <th>STATE: </th>

                    <td><output name="o_state" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>

                </tr>

                

                 <tr>

                    <th>PHONE: </th>

                    <td><output name="o_phone" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>

                </tr>

                

                 <tr>

                    <th>EMAIL: </th>

                    <td><output name="o_email" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>

                </tr>

                

                 <tr>

                    <th>DOB: </th>

                    <td><output name="o_dob" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>

                </tr>

                

                 <tr>

                    <th>GENDER: </th>

                    <td><output name="o_gender" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>

                </tr>

                

                 <tr>

                    <th>HEIGHT AND WEIGHT: </th>

                    <td><output name="o_heightandweight" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>

                </tr>                

                

                 <tr>

                    <th>TOBACCO: </th>

                    <td><output name="o_tobacco" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>

                </tr>

                

                 <tr>

                    <th>HC: </th>

                    <td><output name="o_hc" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>

                </tr>

                

                <tr>

                    <th>STROKE, HA, CANCER, COPD, HIV: </th>

                    <td><output name="o_baddiseases" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>

                </tr>

                

                 <tr>

                    <th>Rx: </th>

                    <td><output name="o_rx" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>

                </tr>

                

                <tr>

                    <th>PAIN: </th>

                    <td><output name="o_pain" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>

                </tr>

                    

                <tr>

                    <th>INSURED STATUS: </th>

                    <td><output name="o_insuredstatus" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>

                </tr>

                

                <tr>

                    <th>AFFORDABLE RANGE OF PREMIUM: </th>

                    <td><output name="o_premiumrange" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>

                </tr>

                

                <tr>

                    <th>NOTES: </th>

                    <td><output name="o_notes" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>

                </tr>

                

​

​

            </table>

            </div>

        </section>

        <section id = "sec2">

​

                <p>Name:</p><input type="text" name="name"><br>

                <p>City:</p><input type="text" name="city"><br>

                <p>State:</p><input type="text" name="state"><br>

                <p>Phone:</p> <input type="text" name="phone"><br>

                <p>Email:</p> <input type="text" name="email"><br>

                <p>Date of Birth:</p> <input type="text" name="dob"><br>

                <p>Gender:</p> <input type="text" name="gender"><br>

                <p>Height and Weight:</p> <input type="text" name="heightandweight"><br>

                <p>Tobacco:</p> <input type="text" name="tobacco"><br>

                <p>Health Conditions:</p> <input type="text" name="hc"><br>

                <p>Stroke, HA, Cancer, COPD, HIV:</p> <input type="text" name="baddiseases"><br>

                <p>Rx:</p> <input type="text" name="rx"><br>

                <p>Pain:</p> <input type="text" name="pain"><br>

                <p>Insured Status:</p> <input type="text" name="insuredstatus"><br>

                <p>Affordable Range of Premium:</p> <input type="text" name="premiumrange"><br>

                <p>Notes:</p> <textarea type="text" name="notes" rows = "4" cols = "25"></textarea><br>

                <br>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit">

​

        </section>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If the parameters are showing up in your url, then that means the form submitted.

Comment: @Taplar can you tell me why they stop reprinting to the page after a certain period of time?